# Does a collar along the boundary always find an embedding in the manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Suppose we have a smooth manifold $M$ with boundary $K$. $K$ always finds a natural embedding inside $M$. Can we extend this embedding to an embedding of $K\times [0,\epsilon)$ inside $M$ in general ? 
It seems to be the case in all examples that I can think of, but I can not find a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search for "collar neighborhood theorem" led to [this](http://www.math.toronto.edu/vtk/1300Fall2015/lecture-nov2.pdf), in which Theorem 1.0.5 is  the theorem you want (assuming you're talking about smooth manifolds with smooth boundaries, which I'm assuming because you've put "differential geometry" as a tag).

I think that there's also a nice proof of this in Milnor's *Lectures on the h-cobordism Theorem.*

Comment: Wow ! Thanks ! I should have googled it up myself